# What is the meaning of Hrishikesha?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, etymology

All I know is that Krishna or Arjuna is called Hrishikesha. What is the meaning of Hrishikesha?

Comment: Kesha hair hrishi golden colored golden colored hair like sun rays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**हृषीकेश = हृषीक (इन्द्रिय/senses) + ईश (lord)** = Lord of the senses

Hindi Commentary By Swami Chinmayananda and English Commentary By Swami Sivananda on [BG 1.15](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=15&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&choose=1) explain Hrishikesha (used for Krishna) as the Lord of the senses:

> हृषीकेशः (the Lord of the senses) Krishna
> हृषीकेश यह भगवान् का एक नाम है जिसका अर्थ है इन्द्रियों का स्वामी। हृषीक (इन्द्रिय)...

Lord Shiva gives same meaning (Lord of the senses) in in Harivamsha: Bhavisha Parva: Chapter 88:

> [image]